# Odds Against Success By Chance

Tags: odds-ratio

If one can expect to be right 10% of the time, by chance alone, how do you determine the odds against being right 22% of the time by chance alone?

Comment: What does "of the time" mean?  One guess?  Ten guesses? A lifetime's worth??

Comment: Sorry.  100 attempts.  Thanks,

Comment: This is answered by applying a [Binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Binomial+distribution%22+prop*+-negative+-mle+-confidence+-poisson+-beta+prob*+closed%3Ano+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2).